# Sticky Select Option

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php

echo '<select name="transact_day" id="transact_day">';

echo"<option value=''>Select Day</option>";

for($i= 1; $i<=31; $i++){
    echo "<option value=". $i ." ";

      if(isset($day) == "$i"){
                echo 'selected = "selected" ';
      }

   echo ">$i</option>\n";
}
echo '</select>';

?>
```

I want it to be sticky but when a date is selected (e.g 10) and the form is submitted it's only the value 31 that is sticky (irrespective of the selected date). I have tried different options, searched through similar questions but I couldn't figure out what was wrong with the above code. Any suggestion? Thank

Comment: how $day is changed? I assume there should be a wrap loop for $day

Comment: $day is changed when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`isset($day)`](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.isset.php) returns a boolean value, so comparing this to `$i` is incorrect. Check if `$day` is set, then compare `$day` with `$i`:

```
echo '<select name="transact_day" id="transact_day">';

         echo"<option value=''>Select Day</option>";

           for($i= 1; $i<=31; $i++){
            echo "<option value=". $i ." ";

            if(isset($day) && ($day == "$i")){
                echo 'selected = "selected" ';
            }

            echo ">$i</option>\n";
         }
         echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Thanks Ares. The (isset($day) && ($day == "$i")) did the trick.