# Sticky select php. Other Stack Overflow answer doesn't work for me

Tags: php, select, sticky

So I tried going with the answer from [Sticky Select Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105801/sticky-select-option)
which ended up looking like this

```
<option value="2" <?php if(isset($yourDilution && $yourDilution == 2)){ echo 'selected = "selected" '; }?>>1:1</option>
```

and that breaks my code and gives me a syntax error. Alternatively I have

```
<option value="3" <?php if($yourDilution == 3) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>1:2</option>
```

and that gives me the problem I had before coming here to look at other answers on the topic. The problem is that the drop down gets filled with Notice: Undefined variable $yourDilution etc. 
Thanks for taking a minute to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(isset($yourDilution && $yourDilution == 2))
```

should be

```
if(isset($yourDilution) && $yourDilution == 2)
```